# ¿Cómo dibujar cientos de puntos utilizando XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

Estoy realizando una aplicacion en la que debo dibujar en pantalla una **matriz de puntos**, de aproximandamente **90*30**. Como ven, son muchos puntos y tengo dudas acerca de como afrontar el problema.

## **Edito:**

Debo simular un Display de matriz de puntos, el codigo en C# es una matriz de 90*30 con 0 donde un led se apaga y 1 donde un led se enciende. Debo dibujar en base a esa matriz, los apagados de color negro, los encendidos de blanco

He empezado jugar con el codigo creando **2700** objetos de tipo Ellipse, usando esta funcion pongo los primeros 30 en un stack panel vertical y luego lo agrego a otro stackpanel horizontal, llamo esta misma funcion 90 veces y obtengo la matriz. Asi:

```
public void CreateDotsColumn() {
    var DotStack =
        new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        DotStack.Children.Add(
            new Ellipse()
            {
                Width = 5.0,
                Height = 5.0,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                Margin = new Thickness(0.1)
            });
    }
    HorizontalDotStackPanel.Children.Add(DotStack);
}
```

Considero esto una practica terrible ademas de usar 70mb de memoria.
No encuentro una mejor forma, algo como un control que me permita dibujar sobre la pantalla pixel a pixel, como lo haria en PyGame por ejemplo.

Comment: Por que no simplemente anadio eso en la respuesta?

Comment: Un pregunta, ¿Para que necesitas este requerimiento?, dependiendo de esto podria cambiar la respuesta que te propongamos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta técnica

[Updating points in PointCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548988/updating-points-in-pointcollection)

me parece muy buena

Defines una `DataTemplate` en donde usa el `TranslateTransform` para indicar el posicionamiento de cada punto en base a los datos del ViewModel

Entonces con solo definir un array de punton con las cordenadas X-Y puedes posicionar cada uno.
La parte importante esta en aqui

```
<TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
```

permitiendo el posicionamiento del `Ellipse` dentro del `canvas`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bulbs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue" Width="10" Height="10">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                </Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

En tu caso la linea la quitarias ya que solo quieres definir los puntos de la matriz

Comment: He implementado esta solución, es buena porque actualiza automáticamente la vista gracias al binding. Pero consume 90mb de memoria en promedio al dibujar 2700 puntos y actualizarlos todos produce un retraso notable. Alguna idea para optimizarlo?

Comment: 2700 puntos es un numero bastante elevado, esta claro que los datos de las coordenadas de los puntos no generan ese consumo de memoria, sino que seria un tema de render. La aplicacion notas que se relentiza visualmente o solo es un tema del tamaño de memoria ocupada?

Comment: Es solo el tamaño de memoria ocupada.